# how to hide save and print button when pdf is opened in browser using asp.net c#?

Tags: c#, asp.net

i have a problem that i can restrict user to download pdf,i only view the pdf document to user

in a browser my code is below:

```
         string filepath = Server.MapPath(dt.Rows[0]["FilePath"].ToString()); 
         WebClient client = new WebClient();
         Byte[] buffer = client.DownloadData(filepath);
         Response.ContentType = "application/pdf";
         Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "inline;filename=data.pdf#toolbar=0&navpanes=0");
         Response.AddHeader("content-length", buffer.Length.ToString());
         Response.BinaryWrite(buffer);
```

but the above code can't hide the toolbar in browser..please help

Comment: This is not possible!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you ask cannot be achieved on every browser with every PDF reader plugin.  You do not have control over which PDF reader your users may use, for example.

If the user can view the PDF, they can download it.  There is nothing you can do to prevent this.  The only way to prevent them from saving it locally is not to let them view it in the first place.

And even if you were able to prevent the system from allowing the file to be saved, you cannot protect against the [analog hole](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Analog_hole).  The user could simply take a photo of his monitor, for example, or retype the contents into a new document.

Answer (score 1):

**If the user can view it, then they can print it.**

Hiding the Save or Print button does not secure the PDF file, if you need protection in PDF, consider securing the PDF.

Abobe.com : [PDF File Protection](http://www.adobe.com/in/products/acrobat/protect-pdf-security-encryption.html)